# What folders should be excluded from TimeMachine when using fully-online OneDrive?

Tags: time-machine, ms-teams

We recently did a migration in a corporate environment where our Mac users were using a combination of SMB and AFP mounts for network drives, to a Teams OneDrive solution. For a sense of scale, we can assume that the shared data sums up to about 10TB. Right now, I have my OneDrive shares set up to not keep any local files ; everything should be remote and I just did the initial sync from Teams the other day. I am a MacOS Monterey (12.3) user, and the IT department has OneDrive 22.033.0213.0002 (StandAlone) deployed to us.

My problem is that my TimeMachine backups are taking an **extremely** long time. Currently, I have a backup that has been running for close to 18 hours, and is at 45% done (4G copied) and been freeing space for a while now. Disk Utility shows 180G free on this particular TimeMachine disk.

I already have `~/Library/CloudStorage` excluded from backups, and `sysctl debug.lowpri_throttle_enabled=0` set to help speeds things up. Despite this, my backups are taking an extremely long time since enabling OneDrive. Under normal circumstances, this backup would have taken about 30min tops.

Is there anything else that should be excluded from the backups? I am not seeing anything sizable in `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.*` but am sure if the sync metadata is anywhere else.

Comment: Which version of macOS and OneDrive is important - they recently changed to the new macOS file provider when Monterey shit the door to the old sync idiom…